# Running localhost for WKWebkitView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiwebview, wkwebview

Previously, when loading local html content into UIWebView, it would automatically run localhost/server in the background. This server emulation would enable me to load dynamic content through json, for example. Example code below;

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "www/index", ofType: "html")!)))
}
```

I am now trying to implement this into a WKWebView. I can load local html content, but unlike UIWebView, WKWebView does not emulate localhost/server, so I cannot do things like before, such as dynamically load content with json etc. How would I go about running local html content through localhost? If UIWebView had that feature automatically, surely WKWebView should have it right? Code below.

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "www/index", ofType: "html")!)))
}
```

Note: I am using Xcode 9 for this, so WKWebview is being added through Storyboard and the referenced as an outlet.

Many thanks in advance to anybody who can help me with this.

Comment: Hey did it work for you ?

Answer (score 10):

Add below to your info.plist and start the localhost server

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
<dict>  
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>  
    <dict>  
        <key>127.0.0.1:80</key>  
        <dict>  
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>  
            <true/>  
        </dict>  
        <key>localhost:port</key>  
        <dict>  
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>  
            <true/>  
        </dict>  
    </dict>  
</dict>
```

Comment: Hi Cyber. What do you men by starting the localhost server? Is there something I should do before editing the info.plist file?

Comment: No, first add this line and start the localhost server when u compile your app.

Comment: Pay attention to the port you are using. e.g. **localhost:8100**, because "localhost" will call "localhost:80".

Comment: Hi I add your code to plist(change the port to 8080) and set my urlstring to `127.0.0.1:8080/#/login`, but it didn't work. Is there something I missed?

Comment: [Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsapptransportsecurity/nsexceptiondomains#:~:text=Don%E2%80%99t%20include%20a%20port%20number) says not to add port